# PostgreSQL chooses to seq scan huge table instead of index lookup

Tags: postgresql, query-performance, execution-plan, postgresql-performance

I have a table, `account_balance`, with primary key `(address, timestamp, currency)`. This table is pretty big, having nearly 1 billion rows and taking ~3T of space. I am doing a simple query on it:

```sql
SELECT address, EXISTS(SELECT address FROM account_balance WHERE address = a.address) ex
FROM (VALUES ('ab566dceac0d857dbf05682d1ceb548667cf4580')) AS a(address);
```

This should be a simple index lookup but instead Postges produces a seq scan. Here's explain result:

```
Result  (cost=0.37..0.38 rows=1 width=33)
  InitPlan 1 (returns $0)
    ->  Seq Scan on account_balance  (cost=0.00..355882209.06 rows=965801108 width=0)
          Filter: ((address)::text = 'ab566dceac0d857dbf05682d1ceb548667cf4580'::text)
```

If I set `set  enable_seqscan = off` then as expected:

```
Result  (cost=0.99..1.00 rows=1 width=33)
  InitPlan 1 (returns $0)
    ->  Index Only Scan using account_balance_pkey on account_balance  (cost=0.83..153234426.09 rows=965801135 width=0)
          Index Cond: (address = 'ab566dceac0d857dbf05682d1ceb548667cf4580'::text)
```

So the question is - why it chooses the seq scan? It should never make sense to prefer seq scan to index lookup on such a huge table. What could compel it to choose to go sequentially over a 3T table (which of course takes forever) instead of going for the index (which takes microseconds)? Is some parameter wrong or some system variable I need to check? I tried `SET random_page_cost = 1` and for some cases it helps, but for others it still insists on using seq scan. Only setting `enable_seqscan` to `off` seems to fix it consistently, but I feel it's a wrong approach.

I am not sure how to interpret the costs numbers - I feel like they may be the key for it, but I can't figure out where they come from and why they are what they are.

This is on PostgreSQL 12.

P.S. Tried to do `ANALYZE`, didn't change anything.

Answer (score 1):

`EXISTS` will stop executing as soon as a result is found, so if that happens early on, a sequential scan will be very fast. Obviously PostgreSQL estimates that very many rows in `account_balance` have that `address`.

The cost estimate on the sequential scan is misleading, since it is for the complete scan. As you see, the final cost is estimated quite low.

Without `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` it is impossible to say if PostgreSQL is right, but then you only asked for an explanation why it would choose such a plan.

Comment: Well, the problem is that `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` for the wrong branch would take forever as it's a 3T DB scan. Getting `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` for index scan is easy but I'm not sure it's useful without the second one. 
It is true that seq scan _might_ be very quick, but the probability of it is very low as there are millions of addresses.

Comment: Try `SELECT 1 FROM account_balance WHERE address = 'ab566dceac0d857dbf05682d1' LIMIT 1;` Sometimes simpler queries are a good idea.